# how to attach a footnote to the 'Notes' which is the head of my endnotes, generated by the endnotes package?

Tags: footnotes, endnotes

When I make endnotes at the end of my document by the 'endnotes' package, it gives a 'Notes' as the heading of the endnote section. Now I need to attach a footnote to that word, how can I achieve that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! And where should that footnote go? A footnote to the page of endnotes seems quite bizarre.

Comment: @egreg directly to the word 'Notes' which appear at the top of my endnotes.

Comment: I understand: you have endnotes all over your document; but you would like to make a footnote to the word "Notes", which is the section title of the section for the endnotes. OK, we've had stranger questions here. And in fact it is funny to footnotes in the endnotes section. But please provide a MWE, so we can start to work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it quite strange, but here it is; in order to avoid confusion, I changed the footnote marker to a symbol.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\originalfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\let\footnote\endnote

\renewcommand{\notesname}{Notes\originalfootnote{This is a footnote}}

\begin{document}

\section{First}
Something with a note\footnote{This is for section 1}

\section{Second}
Something with a note\footnote{This is for section 2}

\section{Third}
Something with a note\footnote{This is for section 3}

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have both footnotes and endnotes, then the change is very simple:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{endnotes}

\renewcommand{\notesname}{Notes\footnote{This is a footnote}}

\begin{document}

\section{First}
Something with a note\endnote{This is for section 1}

\section{Second}
Something with a note\endnote{This is for section 2}

\section{Third}
Something with a note\endnote{This is for section 3}

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can you pls tell me the meanings and functions of the preamble?

Comment: what's more, I also need to add normal footnotes to my file, and this doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @WilsonofGordon I assumed you had only endnotes. I'll add the other case, but I think this is even more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

this is so weird, it's really funny. I've got a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enotez, blindtext}


\begin{document}
\AtEveryEndnotesList{bla\footnote{Fussnote}}
Text with \endnote{\blindtext}

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

It is not really a footnote to the heading, but maybe good enough.